# Перемещение метки и получение новых координат налету

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

прошу помочь, примеров готовых нет, самому не осилить.

Есть карта, на ней куча меток из json. у некоторых меток не правильно указаны координаты (чуть чуть подвинуть надо). Каждая метка имеет свой id

```
{"type": "Feature", "id": '.$id.', "geometry": .... }
```

Хотелось бы так, чтобы можно было кликнуть по метке и зажав кнопку мыши перенести ее на нужное место, как только кнопку мыши отпустил с помощью ajax записать новые координаты для этой метки, где была мышь

Такое можно провернуть?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых проверьте, что метки грузятся не в ObjectManager (он не поддерживает [драггабельность](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject.html#GeoObject__param-options.draggable)), затем пропишите им:

```
draggable: true
```

Затем подпишитесь на [dragend](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject.html#event_detail__event_detail/event-dragend) и получите новые координаты метки:

```
myMap.geoObjects.events.add([
  'dragend'
], function(e) {
  var placemarkPosition = myMap.options.get('projection').fromGlobalPixels(
    myMap.converter.pageToGlobal(e.get('position')),
    myMap.getZoom()
  );
  console.log(placemarkPosition);
});
```